# Gitlab integreate with LDAP login failed with "Invalid credentials"

Tags: ldap, gitlab, qnap

I installed "gitlab-ce-7.14.1-ce.0.el6.x86_64.rpm" on Centos.Everything goes normal but when I try to integrate with LDAP runs on my Qnap NAS. It shows error.

My LDAP account is right definitely. 
Test LDAP account

```
ldapwhoami -D "cn=admin,dc=test,dc=net" -w "ldap" -h 192.168.1.10
```

Response

```
dn:cn=admin,dc=test,dc=net
```

When I try to login with LDAP account from gitlab web. 
error on GitLab Web login page

```
Could not authorize you from Ldapmain because "Invalid credentials".
```

error in production.log

```
Started POST "/users/auth/ldapmain/callback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-02 15:41:59 +0800
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "username"=>"user", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Redirected to http://192.168.1.81/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-02 15:41:59 +0800
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 75ms (Views: 36.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)
```

My configuration file /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-EOS # remember to close this block with 'EOS' below
main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
  label: 'LDAP'
  host: '192.168.1.10'
  port: 389
  uid: 'admin'
  method: 'plain' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
  allow_username_or_email_login: true
  bind_dn: 'cn=admin,dc=test,dc=net'
  password: 'ldap'
  active_directory: false
  base: 'ou=people,dc=test,dc=net'
  user_filter: ''
EOS
```

This question is similar to [Gitlab: LDAP "Invalid credentials", but credentials are right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826047/gitlab-ldap-invalid-credentials-but-credentials-are-right)
but it is different version of Gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

My friends have resolve this issue. Just change

```
 uid: 'admin'
```

to

```
 uid: 'uid'
```

Here is full configuration of /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
external_url 'http://192.168.1.11'

gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-EOS # remember to close this block with 'EOS' below
main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
  label: 'LDAP'
  host: '192.168.1.10'
  port: 389
  uid: 'uid'
  method: 'plain' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
  allow_username_or_email_login: true
  bind_dn: 'cn=admin,dc=test,dc=net'
  password: 'ldap'
  active_directory: false
  base: 'ou=People,dc=test,dc=net'
  user_filter: ''
EOS
```

Thank you everyone.